# Removing string from column after applying mask to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to try to remove specific words from a specific column but only for rows that match a mask I've applied to the df, but I don't want it to just change the data in a copy of the dataframe but also in the original frame itself.

I have tried applying the mask and removing the string but it creates a dataframe with only rows matching the mask and the strings removed. I want to preserve all the rows that don't match the mask as well in the dataframe.

```py
df = df[mask]['column to remove from'].str.replace('string to remove', '')
```

Expected result is df with only mask matching rows being removed and all other rows intact.

Comment: please create sample dataframes and expected output to replicate the questions so that users(both now and in future) don't have to guess what is asked.

Comment: `df.loc[mask, 'specific_column'] = df.loc[mask, 'specific_column'].str.replace('string to remove', '')`